# Button Click - Copy file from APK Package to Android Path. But How?

Tags: java, android, button, copy, main-activity

Im trying to create a simple application which will copy a file from "assets" folder of the APK Package to (e.g. mnt/sdcard/android/data/com.testdev.testapp  when button1 get clicked.

But i don't know how to do this. Is this even Possible or are there any workarounds?

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Call `getAssets()` on any `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`) to get an `AssetManager`.

Step #2: Call `open()` on the `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on your desired asset.

Step #3: Use standard Java file I/O to copy from that `InputStream` to a `FileOutputStream` pointing at a spot on external storage.